# Python BeautifulSoup - to get data <span> tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get  tag data.

Example html:

```
<span class=\"value\">3.99<\/span> average rating,\n
```

This is my code:

```
d = BeautifulSoup(fstuff.text, 'html.parser')
d.select_one("span.average").text
```

But I got this error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-b6b8329a8fe3> in <module>()
----> 1 d.select_one("span.average").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Please help me out!
Thanks!

Comment: Just read your code again, carefully, word by word. There's a typo in it. If you don't see it, explain the code to someone else, and why you think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value `3.99` just use

```
print(soup.select_one('span.value').text)
```

If you want to get `average rating,` use `next_sibling`

```
print(soup.select_one('span.value').next_sibling.strip())
```

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<span class=\"value\">3.99</span> average rating,\n'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('span.value').text)
print(soup.select_one('span.value').next_sibling.strip())
```